# C# Changing ForeColor of label hides everything else

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a file explorer.
Now I want to change the ForeColor of one label. 
But as soon as I add the code for it everything else disappears.

```
lblpath.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("00ff00");
```

When I start the application Form1 will just be empty.

I don't know if I should post my code, because it's quite a bit and I don't know which parts would be relevant...

EDIT:
Method where I use this code:

```
    private void initiateGUI()
    {

        this.Text = "Explorer";
        this.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1a1a1a");

        oneup = new Button();
        oneup.Location = new Point(455, 12);
        oneup.Parent = this;
        oneup.Visible = true;
        oneup.MouseClick += oneup_click;
        oneup.Text = "UP";
        oneup.Width = 40;
        oneup.Height = 20;

        cmdrefresh = new Button();
        cmdrefresh.Location = new Point(500, 12);
        cmdrefresh.Parent = this;
        cmdrefresh.Visible = true;
        cmdrefresh.MouseClick += refresh_click;
        cmdrefresh.Text = "Refresh";
        cmdrefresh.Width = 55;
        cmdrefresh.Height = 20;

        lblfolder.Location = new Point(475, 39);
        lblfolder.Font = font;
        //lblfolder.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        lblfolder.Parent = this;
        lblfolder.Height = 13;
        lblfolder.Text = "Folders";

        lblfile.Location = new Point(12, 39);
        lblfile.Font = font;
        //lblfile.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00ff00");
        lblfile.Parent = this;
        lblfile.Height = 13;
        lblfile.Text = "Files";

        lblpath.Location = new Point(12, 15);
        lblpath.Font = font;
        lblpath.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00ff00");
        lblpath.Parent = this;
        lblpath.Height = 13;
        lblpath.Width = 30;
        lblpath.Text = "Path";

        scrollfolder.AutoScroll = false;
        scrollfolder.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
        scrollfolder.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        scrollfolder.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        scrollfolder.AutoScroll = true;
        scrollfolder.Parent = this;
        scrollfolder.Height = 390;
        scrollfolder.Width = 220;
        scrollfolder.Location = new Point(x2 - 10, y - 10);

        scrollfiles.AutoScroll = false;
        scrollfiles.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
        scrollfiles.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        scrollfiles.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        scrollfiles.AutoScroll = true;
        scrollfiles.Parent = this;
        scrollfiles.Height = 390;
        scrollfiles.Width = 420;
        scrollfiles.Location = new Point(x - 10, y - 10);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a blank form when I debug in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921300/why-do-i-get-a-blank-form-when-i-debug-in-c)

Comment: I don't think so, because if I delete this line of code, it works as intended.

Comment: Maybe there's an exception from this line, so the rest of the method isn't executed.

Comment: I don't think so, because it doesn't work either if I use the "normal" Color.Blue

Comment: Where does this line of code execute? Called from the constructor? Post the method where you call it, along with other calls.

Comment: what happens when you use another color definition e.g. Color.Green?

Comment: Does also not work if I use Color.Green.

Comment: Put try/catch around lblfile.ForeColor assignment (or lblPath whatever). Where's the difference between lblfile/lblpath and lbfolder (where it appears to work)?

Comment: That's missleading. It doesn't work with lblfolder. And If I surround it with a try catch, the form doesn't go blank.

Comment: Yeah - and what's the exception you catch?!

Comment: This is the exeption: "Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.dll"

Comment: There must be a message associated with it...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know where I find this, can you tell me please?

Comment: try { ... } catch(Exception E) { Debug.WriteLine(E.Message); MessageBox.Show(E.Message); } - and/or use E.ToString() which may be more helpful.

Comment: Now if you comment out those color setting lines, the same happens??

Comment: @Elanduir: This still doesn't show **where** you call `initiateGUI`. Presumably within constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I accidently  called it before the label was initiated. Now it works. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the designer to set the colour?

Where did you add this code, to the constructor? Most likely, the statement throws an exception before `InitializeComponents` gets a chance to run - and if you added the code to the constructor, before `InitializeComponents`, it's very likely that `lblpath` doesn't exist yet, so you're getting `NullReferenceException`. Try enabling "break on all exceptions" in the debugger, it's very handy for debugging Winforms applications, since the error will no longer be swallowed.

Use the designer to set the colour, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I don't use the designer to set the color, because I create the label with code. And I added the code to my own function (initiateGUI).

Comment: @Elanduir Okay, and where do you call your `initiateGUI` method?

Comment: I call it in "Form1_Load".

Comment: @Elanduir Well, with what you've shown, it's impossible to see what the problem could be. Have you tried enabling "break on all exceptions"?

Comment: No I haven't, how can I enable this?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `#` in color definition. It should be:

```
lblpath.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00ff00");
```

`ColorTranslator.FromHtml` will throw exception if `"00ff00"` used

Comment: The code you posted in your question is still missing the hash.